# Passing Method into SetTimeOut using CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, settimeout

This is my CoffeeScript code.

```
setTimeout (-> @checkProgress()), 5000
```

When I run this in the browser I get the following error:

```
TypeError: this.checkProgress is not a function
```

The method looks like:

```
checkProgress: ->
    ~ code
    ~ code
    ~ code
    setTimeout (-> @checkProgress()), 5000
```

So at some point I want to call the method again. How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: `@checkProgress` is already a `function`. You do not need to wrap it in another `function`. Just use `setTimeout @checkProgress, 5000`

Comment: In other cases you can use helper: `delay = (t, fn) -> setTimeout(fn, t)`.

Comment: That's what I was doing before but then I read that when doing that the actual function doesn't get called but rather the result of the function ends up in that param position which isn't what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout` run `@checkProgress` in `window` context. Use fat arrow:

```
setTimeout (() => @checkProgress), 5000
```

Comment: This worked, sort of. I ended up getting a different error. Undefined for the variables i was referencing in the method code.

Answer (score 0):

This personally worked perfectly for me as well.

```
recall = =>
          @checkProgress()
        setTimeout recall, 5000
```